# Getting temp session token on behalf of IAM user X

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to generate temporary tokens for user X, by using the credentials of user Y? I could not find any documentation.

I use this code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(awsCreds);
GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
getSessionTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(7200);
GetSessionTokenResult sessionTokenResult = stsClient.getSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = sessionTokenResult.getCredentials();
```

this code creates a temp token that has all the permission of the original access/secret keys. I want temp token with the permissions of an IAM user X

Comment: You simply want the same set of permissions as user X, but not to impersonate user X? Would assuming an IAM role with that same set of permissions give you what you need?

Comment: i just want the permissions. i'm not sure if i understand what assume role is

Comment: Read up on IAM roles. They're very important in AWS for allowing EC2 instances, third parties, and automation in general to get credentials for operating in AWS with specific, minimal permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have just converted your long term credentials into short term temporary credentials - which is good for lots of purposes.

Next, you should create an IAM role with the permissions that you want. Then in STS you call `assumeRole()`. This will create new temporary credentials with the permissions from that role. Note the spelling of assume role depends on the SDK language.

You will still be yourself. STS does not switch user identities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetFederationTokenRequest` or `AssumeRoleRequest` to get temporary credentials and use those. In either case you cannot get permissions of other user.

1. You can get a permission associated with a role by using `AssumeRoleRequest` if you have permission to assumeRoles.
2. You can get permissions associated to your user (subset of it) using `GetFederationTokenRequest`.

However important point is always to use a policy with these calls so that the temporary tokens are used for desired purpose. Eg for get s3 object -

```
Policy policy = policy.withStatements(new Statement(Effect.Allow).withActions(S3Actions.GetObject)
                    .withResources(new Resource("arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/objectKey)));
GetFederationTokenRequest getFederationTokenRequest = new GetFederationTokenRequest();
getFederationTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(3600);
getFederationTokenRequest.setName("username");
getFederationTokenRequest.setPolicy(policy.toJson());
```